# Mule the namespace on the "definitions" element, is not a valid SOAP version

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, mule, cxf

I have a Mule flow that uses the Web Service Consumer to call a SOAP Web Service.

I have checked that the XML that I give to the Web Service Consumer for the request is fine. The XML works fine for instance if I test it in SoapUI.

The same produced XML throws the following error when using the Web Service Consumer component:

```
ERROR 2016-01-26 13:53:00,194 [[api-gateway].http-lc-0.0.0.0-8081.worker.01] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/", the namespace on the "definitions" element, is not a valid SOAP version.. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Type                  : org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException
```

This seems to be like the Web Service Consumer does not detect the Soap Version correctly.

Comment: You need to add details, your xml request your flow and stacktrace.

Comment: You need to add the namespaces in the ws consumer endpoint . Hope it helps

Comment: The strange answer to this question is: I have defined the URL to the Soap Service as http://HostXYZ:postXZY/serviceXZY?wsdl, the issue is with the "?wsdl", if you remove this part the call will work fine. I have seen that a few times now with CXF. Such a strange error message for such a simple error. Remains a mystery why CXF does not like the URL defined with a ?wsdl at the end (or simply not just accepts both formats of the URL)